# tkinter Scroll rendering

Tags: python, tkinter

I have taken an [applied example of using Scrollbar](http://effbot.org/zone/tkinter-autoscrollbar.htm) directly from the tkinter documentation and replaced the two objects of type `AutoScrollbar` to `Scrollbar`, and the `Button` to `Entry`.

The issue at hand is that if I scroll quickly enough, the `Entry` texts become a blur as the entries don't seems to render quickly enough.

Is there a technique wherein all of the elements in the `Frame` of the `Canvas` are pre-rendered and the viewing window simply slides and scales? Or render time simply inevitable in `tkinter`?

Answer (score 0):

I've thought of an interesting solution and I'm open to feedback.

The idea is essentially to create an artificial sort of scrolling wherein the entries are updated in value (using their `StringVar.set()`). One tick on the mousewheel *down* would lead to each of the entries being shifted up 3 units (arbitrary correlation -- could be more or less).

Comment: That sort of updating seems to be lightning fast (I _have_ just managed to test it)